# Fiting non-linear model to small data set

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, small-sample, nls

I want to do a small example with fitting non-linear model
Here are data:

```
x <- c(10, 15, 25)
y <- c(5, 10, 15)
```

Firstly I fit a second degree polynom:

```
mod <- lm(y~x + I(x^2))
```

Than I try to fit non-linear model

```
nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * exp(-b1 * x)), start = c(b = 5, b1 = 0.1, a = 10), trace = T)
```

But it did not converge. I assume it is due to small data set. However, the results of `trace` are ok to achieve my goal

```
0 :   6.9063593  0.1764925 16.3104236
0 :   6.9063593  0.1764925 16.3104236
0 :   6.9063593  0.1764925 16.3104236
Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * exp(-b1 * x)), start = c(b = 5, b1 = 0.1,  : 
  number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
```

The results can be shown on the figure

```
curve(coef(mod)[1] + coef(mod)[2] * x + coef(mod)[3] * x^2, 10, 30, add = T, col = "red")

b = 6.9
b1 = 0.1764
a = 16.31
curve(a *  exp(-b * exp(-b1 * x)), 7, 30, add = T, col = 30)
```

[image]

The question is if I can force the `nls` to converge on such a small data set, or if I can keep somehow the results from trace from notconverged model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the manual of `nls` function you can read

> **Warning**
>
> **Do not use nls on artificial "zero-residual" data.**
>
> The nls function uses a relative-offset convergence criterion that
>   compares the numerical imprecision at the current parameter estimates
>   to the residual sum-of-squares. This performs well on data of the form
>
> y = f(x, θ) + eps
>
> (with var(eps) > 0). It fails to indicate convergence on data of the
>   form
>
> y = f(x, θ)
>
> because the criterion amounts to comparing two components of the
>   round-off error. If you wish to test nls on artificial data please add
>   a noise component, as shown in the example below.

This is the case of your data, you have only three observations, so there is no noise and the function does not converge because of the algorithm used.

Instead, you could simply use the `optim` function, that produces your desired output. You have to simply specify some loss function to minimize (e.g. sum of squared errors) and pass it to the optimizer.

```
f <- function(param) sum((y - (param[1] *  exp(-param[2] * exp(-param[3] * x))))^2)

optim(c(0, 0, 0), f, method = "BFGS")$par
```

Comment: Wow.  Interesting. Talk about a bad (implementation of an) algorithm.  "Making" you add noise to your model so the fit's not too good.  I will not recommend the author(s) of nls for the Nobel Prize in algorithm convergence (termination) criteria. *** FAIL ***

Comment: @MarkL.Stone it is designed for real life data rather and in such cases there is generally no noiseless data... on the other hand, in noiseless examples simple optimizers should not have any problem with fitting any reasonable function.

Comment: I don't buy that as an excuse.  There should be a graceful IMPROVEMENT in matters as the fit gets better. The algorithm shouldn't fail when the fit's too good.  There is no good reason for things to be done as nls does.  Even some very small amount of noise might not be enough, so how much is needed - that's ridiculous. Here's a real-life use case: Use nonlinear least squares to solve a nonlinear system of equations when you don't know in advance whether there is an exact solution, or within what tolerance. If residual is "tolerance level" great, if not, you see the best you can do.